# how to insert pdf with original quality in Confluence?

Tags: pdf, confluence

I have pdf file.

after inserting this toconfluence I cannot read it from confluence page(even in full screen mode).

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

[SharpView High-Res PDF Viewer for Atlassian Confluence](http://www.appfusions.com/display/SHRPVW/Home) was built to allow attachments to be embedded into a Confluence page so you can present directly from Confluence. The viewer allows search, zoom up/down, and others features.

SharpView has an improved feature set over the bundled Confluence PDF viewer.

Comment: I am client. I am not administartor.

Comment: You have 2 ways forward - either ask for the plugin to be installed, or alternatively just add a link to the PDF and hopefully your browser will render the PDF using the standard PDF viewer.